# Unable to connect to a remote Postgresql db in python

Tags: python, postgresql, raspberry-pi, remote-access

I want to connect to a remote Postgresql (installed on raspberry pi) DB in Python. I have followed the example from the link below:

https://opensource.com/article/17/10/set-postgres-database-your-raspberry-pi

using the following code:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect('host=192.xxx.x.x user=pi password = raspberry dbname = test')
```

Not sure what goes wrong. Anybody a solution.

Unfortunately I get the following error:

> psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "pi"
>   FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "pi"

Comment: The remote link has zero to do to your question. But I think, having a space before or after the "`=`" is not okay.

Comment: The remote link shows the python code which is used to connect remotely to a Postgresql db on a raspberry pi. Following that example but that doesn;t work. So link has something to do with my question

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend supplying the credentials as keyword arguments for better readability:

```
psycopg2.connect(
    user="...",
    password="...",
    dbname="...",
    host="...",
)
```

Also, as @peterh mentioned in the comments, your provided credentials might be parsed incorrectly (not in this case though). You can use `psycopg2`'s own parser to confirm the output:

```
psycopg2._psycopg.parse_dsn('host=192.xxx.x.x user=pi password = raspberry dbname = test')
```

Which returns:

```
{'user': 'pi',
 'password': 'raspberry',
 'dbname': 'test',
 'host': '192.xxx.x.x'}
```

All things considered, your error suggests that the User/Password combination is incorrect.